# PostgreSQL: Create array by grouping values of the same id

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, group-by, aggregate-functions

Given the following input data:

| id | category |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | A |
| 2 | R |
| 2 | C |
| 3 | Z |

I aim aiming to get the following output table:

| id | categories |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"A","B"} |
| 2 | {"A","R","C"} |
| 3 | {"Z"} |

using the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id,
                ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT category::VARCHAR FROM test) AS categories
FROM my_table
```

But what I get is the following table:

| id | categories |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"A","B","R","C","Z"} |
| 2 | {"A","B","R","C","Z"} |
| 3 | {"A","B","R","C","Z"} |

How can I obtain the desired output?

Note: The `GROUP BY` clause did not work in this case as I'm not using an aggregation function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using the [`JSON_AGG`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-aggregate.html) aggregation function?

```
SELECT id,
       JSON_AGG(category) AS category
FROM tab
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5bmjtHPswndTYp3aZDmo1y/0).

Comment: I would like to keep it as an array as I then need to compare the content between two arrays...

Comment: then you can use `ARRAY_AGG`, which returns an array, does it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming table has name `test`

```sql
select distinct id,
     array(select distinct category::varchar from test b where b.id = a.id) as categories
from test a
```